# How to Test Solidity Struct in Args?

Tags: solidity, events, struct, unittesting

I have an event, where I forward a `Struct` when issuing it.

But I'm not able to test this with `chai` + `hardhat`, I get the following error:

Here is my `getResult` function, my `struct`, and my emitted `event` and the value that arrives in the test.

[image]

**UNIT TEST**

```
it("Should have emit the event at the beginning of the Election Period!", async () => {
    const RESULT = await contract.getResult();

    await expect(contract.deployTransaction)
        .to.emit(contract, "LogStartElection")
        .withArgs("Beginning of the election period, ballot box released!", RESULT);
});
```

**CONTRACT**

```
interface IHelper {
    struct Vote {
        uint total;
    }

    struct Confirmed {
        uint candidate;
        address[] elector;
        Vote vote;
    }

    struct Abstention {
        address[] elector;
        Vote vote;
    }

    struct ElectionResult {
        uint[6] candidates;
        uint totalConfirmedVotes;
        Confirmed[6] confirmedVotes;
        Abstention abstentionVotes;
    }
}

    emit LogStartElection("Beginning of the election period, ballot box released!", getResult());
   
    function getResult() public view returns (ElectionResult memory) {
        return
            ElectionResult({
                candidates: _candidates,
                totalConfirmedVotes: _totalConfirmedVotes,
                confirmedVotes: _confirmedVotes,
                abstentionVotes: _abstentionVotes
            });
    }
```

**RESULT IN CONSOLE**

```
[
  [
    BigNumber { value: "0" },
    BigNumber { value: "1" },
    BigNumber { value: "2" },
    BigNumber { value: "3" },
    BigNumber { value: "4" },
    BigNumber { value: "5" }
  ],
  BigNumber { value: "0" },
  [
    [
      BigNumber { value: "0" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "0" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "1" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "1" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "2" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "2" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "3" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "3" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "4" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "4" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "5" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "5" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [],
    [ BigNumber { value: "0" }, total: BigNumber { value: "0" } ],
    elector: [],
    vote: [ BigNumber { value: "0" }, total: BigNumber { value: "0" } ]
  ],
  candidates: [
    BigNumber { value: "0" },
    BigNumber { value: "1" },
    BigNumber { value: "2" },
    BigNumber { value: "3" },
    BigNumber { value: "4" },
    BigNumber { value: "5" }
  ],
  totalConfirmedVotes: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  confirmedVotes: [
    [
      BigNumber { value: "0" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "0" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "1" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "1" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "2" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "2" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "3" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "3" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "4" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "4" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ],
    [
      BigNumber { value: "5" },
      [],
      [Array],
      candidate: BigNumber { value: "5" },
      elector: [],
      vote: [Array]
    ]
  ],
  abstentionVotes: [
    [],
    [ BigNumber { value: "0" }, total: BigNumber { value: "0" } ],
    elector: [],
    vote: [ BigNumber { value: "0" }, total: BigNumber { value: "0" } ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Consider switching to [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/). Testing is much easier in Solidity.

Comment: Do you have a solution here? So annoying.